# Is there a malloc variant that zeros out blocks on calling `free()`?

Tags: linux, malloc, customization, libc

I'd like to replace the standard malloc system-wide (via LD_PRELOAD or just replacing the installed libc) with one that zeros out everything what's possible in the freed blocks. Does anyone know an existing solution?

Having zeroes in unused parts of the heap will make compressing it via zram-config much more effective. Since I need the RAM more than the CPU, increased CPU usage is not a problem.

Comment: Do you need to be able to revert to the standard malloc afterward? Otherwise you could just modify the C library on your system.

Comment: @Étienne An already modified and tested libc would be all I need.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could modify the C library on your system. I don't think you'll find a modified C library doing exactly memory allocation that way, because it is non-standard. But the modification sounds relatively easy. Have a look at the implementation of your C library, you could just replace the implementation of free with a wrapper doing free+memset instead of just free.

Comment: Actually ... unfortunately not quite _that_ easy. You cannot _wrap_ `free()` in a simple way because it takes _only an address_ (and no size) as argument. Without knowing the details of the implementation, you can't find the size of the memory block at the given address ... so yes, if you have the sourcecode, you can modify it accordingly. It wouldn't be a "wrapper" though.

Comment: @FrankH: Yeah, I was maybe unclear, I meant something like reimplement free, name the original implementation of free "standard_free", and then use that "standard_free" in your own implementation of free.

Comment: @FrankH. While the change needs some knowledge in order to be implemented, at least in the case of current eglibc, it is comparatively simple. See my answer below for an actual patch.

Comment: @jons34yp I've not said it's hard, merely said that ... just stated you can't wrap it, and need the actual implementation details :-)

Answer (score 2):

Just in case anyone encounters similar issue, below is a patch for eglibc 2.17.

```
--- a/malloc/malloc.c
+++ b/malloc/malloc.c
@@ -1424,10 +1424,16 @@
 #define first(b)     ((b)->fd)
 #define last(b)      ((b)->bk)

+#define zero_sizes(P) {                                                \
+    P->size = 0;                                                        \
+    P->prev_size = 0;                                                   \
+}
+
 /* Take a chunk off a bin list */
 #define unlink(P, BK, FD) {                                            \
   FD = P->fd;                                                          \
   BK = P->bk;                                                          \
+  P->bk = 0; P->fd = 0; \
   if (__builtin_expect (FD->bk != P || BK->fd != P, 0))                \
     malloc_printerr (check_action, "corrupted double-linked list", P); \
   else {                                                               \
@@ -1449,9 +1455,11 @@
       } else {                                                         \
         P->fd_nextsize->bk_nextsize = P->bk_nextsize;                       \
         P->bk_nextsize->fd_nextsize = P->fd_nextsize;                       \
       }                                                                \
+      P->fd_nextsize = 0;                                               \
+      P->bk_nextsize = 0;                                               \
     }                                                                  \
   }                                                                    \
 }

 /*
@@ -1878,8 +1886,10 @@

 static int perturb_byte;

-#define alloc_perturb(p, n) memset (p, (perturb_byte ^ 0xff) & 0xff, n)
-#define free_perturb(p, n) memset (p, perturb_byte & 0xff, n)
+#define alloc_perturb(p, n) do {} while(0)
+#define free_perturb(p, n) memset (p, 0, n)


 /* ------------------- Support for multiple arenas -------------------- */
@@ -3809,8 +3819,7 @@
       }
     }

-    if (__builtin_expect (perturb_byte, 0))
-      free_perturb (chunk2mem(p), size - 2 * SIZE_SZ);
+    free_perturb (chunk2mem(p), size - 2 * SIZE_SZ);

     set_fastchunks(av);
     unsigned int idx = fastbin_index(size);
@@ -3892,13 +3901,13 @@
       goto errout;
     }

-    if (__builtin_expect (perturb_byte, 0))
-      free_perturb (chunk2mem(p), size - 2 * SIZE_SZ);
+    free_perturb (chunk2mem(p), size - 2 * SIZE_SZ);

     /* consolidate backward */
     if (!prev_inuse(p)) {
       prevsize = p->prev_size;
       size += prevsize;
+      unlink_free(p);
       p = chunk_at_offset(p, -((long) prevsize));
       unlink(p, bck, fwd);
     }
@@ -3910,6 +3921,7 @@
       /* consolidate forward */
       if (!nextinuse) {
         unlink(nextchunk, bck, fwd);
+        zero_sizes(nextchunk);
         size += nextsize;
       } else
    clear_inuse_bit_at_offset(nextchunk, 0);
@@ -4069,6 +4081,7 @@
      if (!prev_inuse(p)) {
        prevsize = p->prev_size;
        size += prevsize;
+       zero_sizes(p);
        p = chunk_at_offset(p, -((long) prevsize));
        unlink(p, bck, fwd);
      }
@@ -4079,6 +4092,7 @@
        if (!nextinuse) {
          size += nextsize;
          unlink(nextchunk, bck, fwd);
+         zero_sizes(nextchunk);
        } else
          clear_inuse_bit_at_offset(nextchunk, 0);
```

Answer (score 1):

Why not write your own `free_zero` function?

```
void free_zero(void *p, size_t n)
{
   volatile unsigned char *zp = p;

   if (!p) return;

   while (n--)
   {
       *zp++ = 0;
   }

   free(p);
}
```

Comment: Or use `memset (p, 0, n)` rather than a loop?

Comment: @ChrisJ well the problem with `memset` is a "smart" compiler would have the right to optimize it out

Comment: @ouah "optimizing `memset()` out" doesn't mean the block-fill will not be done. If the compiler / standard library chooses to implement `memset()` as `inline` then you won't see a call to it in the generated code, but the effect must remain.